# Samsung Galaxy Nexus S3 issues rendering View Objects (multiple issues)

Tags: android

1. Device: Samsung Galaxy Nexus
2. Install: device is mostly blank, used really only for development
3. Android Version: 4.2.2

So I started working a project today. I noticed that when I typed into an `EditText object` using the default on screen keyboard that not only was the hint I set not going away but there were white vertical lines on either side of each character I typed.

I messed around with the properties (though I barely did anything but the minimum to add an EditText via XML). After a while I send my apk to a co-worker and asked him to run it on his device (not a Galaxy Nexus). The screen cap he sent me showed no such errors. I decided to ignore it and move on.

The rest of my day has been odd issues that really shouldn't be happening. One example was I had an Activity with a fragment and after a task I attempted to simply switch out the fragments. (they were added programmatically to a `FrameLayout ViewGroup` in the activities layout (after other methods failed)). The new fragment would be added but the old would still show. Pressing home/recent and returning to the app removed the fragment that shouldn't have been showing at all. I then decided to simply change the layout file I was using to `setContentView` of the activity instead of switching activities. Same result. I tried to inflate the contentView View myself and later call `View.setVisible(View.GONE)` (later trying `View.INVISIBLE` as well). With no luck. Also worth mentioning that calls to invalidate (on pretty much anything I could think of) also did not make the removed content to disappear.

So I guess my question is what the heck could possible be causing all this chaos? Has anyone ever experienced issue like this?

Current Activity Code (only method is the onCreate() so far):

```
private View layout1, layout2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    layout1 = factory.inflate(R.layout.building_list, null);
    layout2 = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_files, null);
    super.setContentView(layout1);

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}
            catch(Exception e){}

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    FilesActivity.this.setContentView(layout2);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

XML code for layout1:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/build_list_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pin_wheel"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:text="@string/building_list_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pin_wheel"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

XML code for layout2:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/files_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/files_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="List Of Files Go here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna - Thanks for the edit. I accidentally bumped my enter key and it posted before I had a chance to prof-read. I was in the middle of reading it over and was about to fix stuff, but I guess you beat me to it!

Comment: Your welcome, No Problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If others are having odd rendering issues. Such as text displaying improperly. `View` objects that have been removed continue to display (and I'm sure there are many many more). You should try changing your app's base theme to something different (most likely, for others, this is at res/values/styles.xml). Also check that all your activities listed in your manifest file actually use the theme you think they are using (if you don't set theme's per activity make sure that `View` objects that need specific styles have been set as such).

Example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > <!-- this line, if you are using a custom theme it should be used here-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```